# Should we have a MAL tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I feel that many users of this site also use My Anime List (MAL) to track and organize their anime. Thus, would it not make sense for us to have a MAL tag for questions?

Answer (score 6):

Like include the tag in every question? That wouldn't make sense. Tags are used to denote that the question is directly related to something. We could as well add [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) tag to most of our questions, and it wouldn't be very useful.

If we had a number of questions that would be on topic and asking about something directly related to MyAnimeList site in a way that would make sense to use a tag for it… actually, I can't even imagine such a scenario.

Comment: I was more thinking about questions specifically dealing with MAL and the website, but now that I'm reconsidering it's probably considered off-topic for this website.

Comment: Well, yes, because we mainly deal with questions directly related to anime or manga, and not the resources related to them. I guess we might have a few exceptions but in this case I just don't know how it could possibly fit unless the site became a known anime producer or a distribution network like [CrunchyRoll](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crunchyroll).

Comment: @ThePickleTickler if the question is about MyAnimeList then it might make sense however i don't recall any question like that. i do recall answers which talk about MyAnimeList in which we don't normally update tags in a question to reflect the answers that have been posted which is why, before they were made off-topic, id requests weren't updated to have a series tag after they were answered

Answer (score 3):

Tag [myanimelist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myanimelist) now exists and was first created in October 2018 on [Is MyAnimeList still good ranking site for anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/49147/2516).

Note that as [Hakase's answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3884/2516) has mentioned, **use this tag only for questions about MyAnimeList specifically**.